# Passar Variable a otro Php

Tags: php, session, cookies

Mi problema es que quiero enviar unas variables a de un archivo php a otro php en el primer archivo hago un insert a la base de datos y en el otro quiero los datos porque enviara u correo con pdf adjuto.

Estoy intentando enviar las variables por session pero no recibo nada en el otro archivo.

Archivo 1. Desde donde envio los datos.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('dbconnect_create.php');

//Recuperar les dades enviades des del ajax
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$persones = $_POST['persones'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$hora = $_POST['hora'];

//Insert a la BD
$query  = "INSERT into `reservas` (nom, apellidos,  email, telefon, persones, data, hora)
            VALUES ('$nom', '$apellidos' , '$email', '$telefon', '$persones', '$data', '$hora')";
    
//Executar l'insert
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$_SESSION['nom'] = $nom;
$_SESSION['apellidos'] = $apellidos;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;
$_SESSION['hora'] = $hora;
```

?>

Archivo 2 donde quiero recibirlos.

```
<?php
    session_start();
        //Base de dades
        ob_start();
        include ('../bd/dbconnect_create.php');
    
        $nom = $_SESSION['nom'];
        $apellidos = $_SESSION['apellidos'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $data = $_SESSION['data'];
        $hora = $_SESSION['hora'];

        //canviar format de la data a Dia-Mes-Any
        $data_correcta = $data_correcta = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data));

        //Query de la reserva 
        $sql ="select * from reservas where nom = '$nom' and apellidos = '$apellidos' and data = '$data' and hora = '$hora'";
        $re = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        //Crear array de la query per poder recore i escollir quin camp 
        while($row = $re->fetch_assoc()) $reserva[] = $row;

        echo $nom.$apellidos.$email.$data.$hora;
```

Comment: ¿Los archivos están en servidores distintos? Si están en el mismo servidor basta con hacer `include` o `require` del primer archivo en el segundo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema puede estar en el ob_start() , que limpia los buffers y reinicia la información de los mismos. Te recomiendo que leas [este artículo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) donde hay un ejemplo de como enviar variables en $_SESSION.

Comment: En el caso de que esto no funcione, también podrías agregar un condicional para saber si iniciar una sesión o no. Algo como:
 if (!isset($_SESSION) { session_start(); }.
Espero que te sirva de ayuda!